# Adjusting image contrast in FIB/SEM image - without affecting the text bar at the bottom of the image

Tags: dm-script

FIB/SEM images have a text bar at the bottom of the image.
When imported into GMS, any contrast, gamma, .. adjustment also affects the text bar.

Is it possible to break up the image and have the data processing affect only the actual image - not the text bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best you can do here is to break the actual image array into 2 separate images and then have the text-bar section displayed as a separate imageDisplay which you can add onto the imageDisplay of the data. You can shift/scale them with respect to each other, and you can also lock the added display so that it can not be shifted by mouse anymore. The following example should do what you need:

```
void CropAndMerge(Image img, number h){
         number sx = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(0)
         number sy = img.ImageGetDimensionSize(1)
         image data := img.slice2(0,0,0,0,sx,1,1,sy-h,1).ImageClone()     // note ":=", we sub-slice keeping tags and all
         image anno = img.slice2(0,sy-h,0,0,sx,1,1,h,1) // note "=", we just want the data copy
         
         
         imageDisplay disp 
         // Simple way to get imageDisplay. First show, then grab
         //       data.ShowImage()
         //       disp = data.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
         
         // Better alternative: No need to show
         imageDocument doc = NewImageDocument( img.ImageGetName() )
         doc.ImageDocumentAddImage( data )
         //       doc.ImageDocumentAddImage( anno )    // Use this to add 'side ordered' in case of page-view type. However, I'd rather not use page-mode.
         disp = data.ImageGetImageDisplay(0)
         disp.ImageDisplaySetColorTableByName( "Black Body Extended" )    // Just to show you can act on the display before actually showing it that way
         
         // Add Annotation area as annotation on imageDisplay (all are components)
         imageDisplay annoDisp = NewImageDisplay( anno, "best" )
         disp.ComponentAddChildAtEnd( annoDisp )
         
         // move out of the way
         // ComponentPositionAroundPoint: Moves the annotation so the 'rel_x' horizontal point in the bounding rect is at 'new_x' (if bool horz is true), and for y accordinglye
         number doVert = 1
         number rel_y = 1.0 // bottom (relative coordinate!)
         number new_y = sy  // becomes bottom (absolute position)
         annoDisp.ComponentPositionAroundPoint( 0,new_y,0,rel_y,0,doVert)
         
         // make sure nobody messes with the annotation area
         annoDisp.ComponentSetSelectable(0)
         
         doc.ImageDocumentShow()
}

number sx = 1024
number sy = 1024
number h = 300
image in := realimage("Imported",4,sx,sy)
in = (icol%100 + iradius*sin(irow/iheight*5*Pi() + itheta )**2)
in.slice2(0,sy-h,0,0,sx,1,1,h,1) = (icol+irow)%50>45?max(in)+100:0
//in.showimage()

CropAndMerge(in.imageClone(),h)
```